# How to inject the datasource into a data layer, slick debug output

Tags: scala, slick

1. How can I output the generated raw SQL that my slick query will send to mysql? (for debug purposes)
2. Can someone suggest a pattern where I could, on a per request basis, pass a dataSource (jdbc pool) to my data layer?

The idea is I might have 10 different database pools, each connecting to a different database.  I would like to pass in this dataSource dynamically on a per request basis to my data layer based on the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 `someQuery.selectStatement``

2 How about

```
  // somewhere central
  def getDataSourceForUser(user: User) = /* <- your user to DS mapping here */
  def db(user: User) = Database.fromDataSource(getDataSourceForUser(user))

  // in your query code:
  db(currentUser).withSession{ implicit session =>
    // <- your queries here
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, is there a design dock for Slick?  I was looking at it, and boy it looks complicated with AST's etc.!  Do you need a phd to follow it? :)

Comment: No docs on the trees. We should have more docs in the code there at some point. There is one small webcast on the Slick site, but touches only a fraction. Enabling logging can help understand the ASTs: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/codegen/resources/logback.xml